# How to say "(regional/national) identity" in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice

For "identity" or "(regional/national) identity", I found many phrases:

_身份认同

_区域身份

_区域认同感

_地区认同

_拉丁美洲身份

(There are also translations like 区域特征, but the sense here doesn't encompass the idea of "feeling to belong to...").

**Question:**

To be specific, how would we translate the expression "taiwanese identity" that is common in Western outlets?
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=taiwanese+identity

I wonder whether the Taiwanese literary movement 乡土文学 (commonly translated as "nativist literature" or "regional literature") could be translated as "identity literary movement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“identity”, would be translated as “**身份認同**”, or “**身分認同**” in most circumstances

the other four options were, . . . unimaginable

> how would we translate the expression "taiwanese identity"

**台人身分認同**

[https://tw.news.yahoo.com/台人身分認同差異粉碎北京統-希望-bbc-中國要的台灣已消失-071218198.html](https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E5%8F%B0%E4%BA%BA%E8%BA%AB%E5%88%86%E8%AA%8D%E5%90%8C%E5%B7%AE%E7%95%B0%E7%B2%89%E7%A2%8E%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E7%B5%B1-%E5%B8%8C%E6%9C%9B-bbc-%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E8%A6%81%E7%9A%84%E5%8F%B0%E7%81%A3%E5%B7%B2%E6%B6%88%E5%A4%B1-071218198.html)

**台灣人身份認同**

https://www.hk01.com/article/982841?utm_source=01articlecopy&utm_medium=referral

**台灣認同**

https://www.twreporter.org/a/identity-twstory

https://www.twreporter.org/i/draw-taiwaness-recognition/index.html

edited

about “鄉土文學”, i disagreed that it’s “台灣身份認同文學運動”

if one need an english term, maybe “taiwanese literature”

my reading experiences of literatures of hong kong, taiwan & china is, they’ve separate, unique themes since 1950s

for taiwan, [“眷村”](https://tcmb.culture.tw/zh-tw/subject/295) is a common topic, not appeared in other two places

for china, great leap forward, cultural revolution, being a party member or not, these’re common themes

for hong kong, how to be rich, love & good food are more common

as usual, further discussion would need to clarify the definition of “鄉土文學”

btw, an “incident” [千島湖事件](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E5%8D%83%E5%B2%9B%E6%B9%96%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6) in 1994, there’s significance change in the identification

> 以案件發生時間1994年3月31日為界，在之前2月底進行的民意測驗，與4月底同樣的民調比較，**認為「自己是台灣人」由29.1%增加為36.9%**；認為「自己是中國人」由24.2%減少為12.7%

the newest research:  [政大研究：2.4%自認中國人創32年新低](https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E6%94%BF%E5%A4%A7%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6-2-4-%E8%87%AA%E8%AA%8D%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E4%BA%BA%E5%89%B532%E5%B9%B4%E6%96%B0%E4%BD%8E-094620349.html)

> 根據政治大學選舉研究中心最新研究結果，**認同自己是台灣人的人達61.7％**、認同是中國人的只有2.4％，創下1992年以來新低。

have fun :)

Comment: One little question: could the taiwanese "乡土文学" be also referred to as 台湾身份认同文学运动?

Comment: @Starckman, i added info in the answer, please reread 

Comment: 那你覺得"鄉土文學"可以被歸納為一種”身份認同文學運動“嗎？因為我大概記得是這麼學過，就是這個運動，是一種尋找台灣的身分的一次文學運動

Comment: @Starckman, “ 鄉土文學"可以被歸納為一種”身份認同文學運動” **no** 鄉土文學 existed since 1930s (there’re books like 日據時期臺灣鄉土文學的當代紀事, 文學的流離與回歸：三○年代鄉土文學論戰) and the emerging of “台灣意識” / “臺灣主體性” was in 1990s  https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/臺灣主體性